# Argument list too long on bash 4.x but not bash 3.x

Tags: bash, find, touch, sudo, xargs

I use some scripts like

`sudo find . -print0 | xargs -0 sudo touch -ch`

and

`sudo find . -print0 | xargs -0 sudo xattr -c`

to clean things on my machine, and everything works fine on bash 3.x. But when I run this on bash 4.x, I get

`sudo: unable to execute /usr/bin/touch: Argument list too long`

or something similar for other commands. I read the help, but didn't find anything about this.

Comment: I don't see any way this could depend on the shell. `sudo` doesn't use the shell to execute the command.

Comment: unix.stackexchange.com or superuser.com would be better places for this question.